# Error with installing Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I just finish to copy the Prestashop file in my server, but when I open the link in the "install" folder gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Adapter_ServiceLocator' not found in
>   /../config/bootstrap.php on line 29

I already tried to clear the cache , but it does not work

I have Prestashop 1.6.1.4
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In config/defines.inc.php
set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` on `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);`
And you will see the exact error

Comment: i 've already done and it shows me that error "Fatal error: Class 'Adapter_ServiceLocator' not found in /../config/bootstrap.php on line 29"

Comment: @Giacomo15 Where did you download it from? Does your copy has a folder named Adapter in it? Also, is this a clean installation, or are you overwriting an existing older version of Prestashop you had installed already? Basically, first make sure all the files are actually on your server. Then check file permissions.

Comment: I've just downloaded from the official website , and it is a new installation